Can't find eth in wallet
on 4/30 I moved .3 eth from Arbitrum on MM to my phantom eth wallet address.  I have the eth wallet turned on.  I never found the eth.  I have the transaction hash. Just trying to find out if it's lost forever or if I have something wrong in my settings.

0x99b1aeef90b54fff2705375f51cc3bcf32c70606b23bc4a7ddcb257c80989c08

0x99b1aeef90b54fff2705375f51cc3bcf32c70606b23bc4a7ddcb257c80989c08
